# Can the same wildcard SSL certificate be used on different IP addresses and/or boxes?

Tags: ssl, ip, ssl-certificate, hostname, wildcard

Example:

Wildcard SSL certificate for ***.example.com** installed on two different boxes.

```
hostEU.example.com  A  60.70.80.90
hostUS.example.com  A  200.210.220.240
```

I assume this is a perfectly valid scenario, where the actual hostnames *do not* reside on the same IP (or even the same box for that sake).

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, there is not technical limitation for this; except if your CA prohibits this use explicitly.

The most frequently limitation given by a CA is on the "physical servers", but may be someone limits even on IP basis.

As an example, [Geotrust Wildcard Ssl](http://www.rapidssl.com/geotrust/geotrust_wildcard_ssl.htm) says:

> If you need to span the wildcard
>   certificate across multiple physical
>   servers, you may purchase additional
>   licenses.

Comment: Can you give a real-world example of a CA effectively prohibiting the use of a wildcard cert on multiple IP addresses?

Comment: I don't think I have seen anything mentioning multiple IP addresses, but I have seen several examples where installing the cert on multiple 'servers' violates the TOS.  I wasn't checking the wildcard TOS specifically.  See the Geotrust QuickSSL cert for an example of that is tied to one 'server'.

Comment: Yup - GlobalSign wildcard certs can only be installed on 3 hosts, unless you buy licenses for more.

Comment: Pfft, tell them to go stuff their ToS up their collective fundaments.  Ridiculous and inappropriate restrictions ftl.

Comment: @womble, I don't think anyone disagrees.  In many ways the whole SSL Certificate system is a scam.  (http://blogs.techrepublic.com/security/?p=2550)

Comment: Even if prohibited by the CA, can they actually find out? And if so, what can they do, revoke it?

Comment: And (apart from making additional money) why would the CA prohibit it?

Comment: I found a related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/51067/which-wildcard-ssl-cert-vendors-allow-you-to-set-up-the-same-cert-on-multiple-ser

Comment: @mr-euro, they could potentially find out, or at least get see something that looks suspicious if they made several make requests to the the site, and got back a different result for the server/OS.  I don't of any CAs with a such a policy that are actively checking though.

Comment: Thx for all the helpful comments.

Comment: @mr-euro - yes they can just revoke the ssl. And the reason is just to make money, like the entire SSL business is. It's a rip-off but they have the consumer market cornered so you have to play by their rules.

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of CAs do limit you to set number of "physical" server. Certainly my experience of Comodo is such.

But can the ToS being avoiding when you deploy on a cluster of "virtual" machines?